# Golang CGo: converting union field to Go type

Tags: go

I'm working with this C struct on a 64 bit platform, trying to access the **ui32v** field in the **value** union:

```
struct _GNetSnmpVarBind {
  guint32       *oid;       /* name of the variable */
  gsize     oid_len;    /* length of the name */
  GNetSnmpVarBindType   type;       /* variable type / exception */
  union {
    gint32   i32;           /* 32 bit signed   */
    guint32  ui32;          /* 32 bit unsigned */
    gint64   i64;           /* 64 bit signed   */
    guint64  ui64;          /* 64 bit unsigned */
    guint8  *ui8v;          /*  8 bit unsigned vector */
    guint32 *ui32v;         /* 32 bit unsigned vector */
  }         value;      /* value of the variable */
  gsize     value_len;  /* length of a vector in bytes */
};
```

I could write a C wrapper function for each union element but for didactic purposes I'd rather work in Go. Here's how I'm trying to access the **ui32v** field:

```
func union_to_guint32_ptr(cbytes [8]byte) (result *_Ctype_guint32) {
  buf := bytes.NewBuffer(cbytes[:])
  var ptr uint64
  if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &ptr); err == nil {
    return (*_Ctype_guint32)(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
  }
  return nil
}
```

However this gives an error **cannot convert ptr (type uint64) to type unsafe.Pointer**

So how *do* I convert a **uint64** to a Go type that points to a C guint32? I've tried various combinations of casting to a uintptr then casting to a *_Ctype_guint32, casting to a uintptr then using unsafe.Pointer, ...

My reasoning is: I'm passed an array of 8 bytes. Convert that to a uint64, that's the memory address. Cast that to a pointer to a guint32 (ie a C array of guint32's), and return that as a result - that is the union field "value" as a guint32 *.

---

**Context**

Later I'll want to convert the C array of guint32's to a string utilising the value_len field, using a function I know already works:

```
guint32_star := union_to_guint32_ptr(data.value)
result += OidArrayToString(guint32_star, data.value_len)
```

The C code is from [gsnmp](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/gsnmp/0.3.0/annotated.html).

Answer (score 7):

cgo exposes a union as a byte array large enough to hold the largest member of the union. In your case that is 64 bits which are 8 bytes, `[8]byte`. As you've demonstrated, the contents of this array hold the contents of the union and using it is a matter of pointer conversion.

However, you can use the *address of the array* to greatly simplify the process. For a `C._GNetSnmpVarBind` named `data`,

```
guint32_star := *(**C.guint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&data.value[0]))
```

I didn't fully understand this the first time I saw it, but it became more clear when I broke it down:

```
var data C._GNetSnmpVarBind    // The C struct
var union [8]byte = data.value // The union, as eight contiguous bytes of memory

// The first magic. The address of the first element in that contiguous memory
// is the address of that memory. In other words, the address of that union.
var addr *byte = &union[0]

// The second magic. Instead of pointing to bytes of memory, we can point
// to some useful type, T, by changing the type of the pointer to *T using
// unsafe.Pointer. In this case we want to interpret the union as member
// `guint32 *ui32v`. That is, T = (*C.guint32) and *T = (**C.guint32).
var cast **C.guint32 = (**C.guint32)(unsafe.Pointer(addr))

// The final step. We wanted the contents of the union, not the address
// of the union. Dereference it!
var guint32_star *C.guint32 = *cast
```

Credit goes to Alan Shen's [article](https://sunzenshen.github.io/tutorials/2015/05/09/cgotchas-intro.html) which described the cgo representation of a union in a way that finally made sense to me.

Comment: I'm curious: does `guint32_star := *(**C.guint32)(unsafe.Pointer(&data.value)` (without the `[0]` work for you? I've got some code that looks like:

`*(**C.Foo)(unsafe.Pointer(&data.value)) = C.CreateFoo(c_myString)`

Where `C.CreateFoo` returns a `*C.Foo` and this seems to work.

Answer (score 5):

The solution was first to cast to **uintptr**, then cast to **unsafe.Pointer** ie two separate casts:

```
func union_to_guint32_ptr(cbytes [8]byte) (result *_Ctype_guint32) {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(cbytes[:])
    var ptr uint64
    if err := binary.Read(buf, binary.LittleEndian, &ptr); err == nil {
        uptr := uintptr(ptr)
        return (*_Ctype_guint32)(unsafe.Pointer(uptr))
    }   
    return nil 
}
```

I checked this by comparing results with a command line tool, and it's returning correct results.

---

Context

```
// gsnmp._Ctype_gpointer -> *gsnmp._Ctype_GNetSnmpVarBind
data := (*C.GNetSnmpVarBind)(out.data)

switch VarBindType(data._type) {
case GNET_SNMP_VARBIND_TYPE_OBJECTID:
    result += "GNET_SNMP_VARBIND_TYPE_OBJECTID" + ":"
    guint32_star := union_to_guint32_ptr(data.value)
    result += OidArrayToString(guint32_star, data.value_len)
```

Comment: It's sad that, if that's correct, there's no sans-unsafe way to go. Or is there?

Comment: BTW, check the documentation for [`unsafe.Pointer`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe#Pointer), there are extra rules you need to follow and I suspect your use of `uintptr(…)` and `unsafe.Pointer(…)` in separate expressions is invalid (i.e. it can introduce data races via things like garbage collection meaning the end result is completely undefined).

Answer (score 3):

Sonia already answered her own question, I just want to provide the reason for why two type conversions are necessary.

From the documentation for [unsafe.Pointer](http://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer):

> 1) A pointer value of any type can be converted to a Pointer.
>
> 2) A Pointer can be converted to a pointer value of any type.
>
> 3) A uintptr can be converted to a Pointer.
>
> 4) A Pointer can be converted to a uintptr.

Since `var ptr uint64` is not a pointer (as type `uint64` is not a pointer), `ptr` cannot be converted directly to `unsafe.Pointer` using rule 1. Therefore it is necessary to first convert `ptr` to `uintptr`, then from `uintptr` to a `Pointer` following rule 3.

Comment: Also note that rule #3 explicitly states both conversions must be in the same expression. I.e. `p2 := unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(p))` is okay but `u := uintptr(p); p2 := unsafe.Pointer(u)` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

From the CGO [documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/cgo/):

> To access a struct, union, or enum type directly, prefix it with struct_, union_, or enum_, as in C.struct_stat.

So I *guess* (not tested) the code might be something similar to:

```
myUint32var := somePtrTo_GNetSnmpVarBind.union_guint32
```

for accessing the guint32 member of the union of the struct pointed to by `somePtrTo_GNetSnmpVarBind`

Comment: Thanks jnml, I'm not sure of syntax - what if there are multiple unions in the same struct? I grep'd thru the go packages for examples of using C unions, couldn't find any helpful examples. But I got the code to work, see my posted solution.

Comment: In the specific case of the OP, I would then probably try `p.union_value.guint32` or `p.value.union_guint32` or ...? Please post later the correct version, if any, as an answer to your question for others' reference. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again jnml :-) I've posted my solution; I'll have a play with your suggested syntax's tomorrow - it's nearly 1am here :-0